# How to count the number of the same value in select input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Guys i need help with jquery. I have this table http://jsfiddle.net/msx20/PLHSV/1/

And i want to to count the number of the same value in select input for a row an column dynamicly, and display result in table cells with specify class.

- colcountPlus, colcountMinus, colcountN - for summary number of the same values of select for current column
- rowcountPlus, rowcountMinus, rowcountN - for summary number of the same values of select for current row

I try to make this in jQuery but my code didnt work at all, my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fields select').change(function () {
        getCount($(this));
    });



    function getCount() {
        var count = 0;
        $(':selected .fields').live('click', function (.val)) {
            if ($(this).val() == '+') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .rowcountPlus').text(count);
            } else if ($(this).val() == '-') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .rowcountMinus').text(count);
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'N') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .rowcountN').text(count);
            } else if ($(this).val() == '+') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .colcountPlus').text(count);
            } else if ($(this).val() == '-') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .colcountMinus').text(count);
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'N') {
                count++;
                $('tr td:first .colcountN').text(count);
            }
        });
}
```

But it didnt work at all, i have error in line :  $(':selected .fields').live('click', function (.val)) { , and at the end of the code }.

Also i want to select allthe test cells by input select deselect all.

Could anyone help me with this code ? I have search the stack but i havent found any even similar problem.

Comment: I might give an example later, but just some comments now:
1. you bind a change event to ".fields select" this is not right, it should be "select.fields"
2. live is a deprecated method in jQuery

Comment: Are you looking for this: **http://jsfiddle.net/PLHSV/4/** (just an idea to show you how to do it for rows. you can devise a logic to compute columns similarly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $table = $('table'),
        $trPlus = $table.find('tbody tr:nth-last-child(3)'),
        $trMinus = $table.find('tbody tr:nth-last-child(2)'),
        $trDeny = $table.find('tbody tr:nth-last-child(1)');

    $table.find('select').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            column = $(this).parent().index(),
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
            $rowels = $tr.find('select'),
            $colels = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ') select');

        var rowt = total($rowels);
        $tr.find('.countPlus').text(rowt['+'] || 0);
        $tr.find('.countMinus').text(rowt['-'] || 0);
        $tr.find('.countDeny').text(rowt['n'] || 0);

        var colt = total($colels);
        $trDeny.find('td:nth-child(' + (column - 1) + ')').text(colt['n'] || 0);
        $trMinus.find('td:nth-child(' + (column - 1) + ')').text(colt['-'] || 0);
        $trPlus.find('td:nth-child(' + (column - 1) + ')').text(colt['+'] || 0);
    });
    //to initialize the table
    $table.find('tbody tr:nth-child(2) select').change();

    function total($selects) {
        var totals = {};
        $selects.each(function () {
            var val = this.value;
            totals[val] = (totals[val] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return totals;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X7Lwy/)